# Using google maps with react - how to create onerror message if map cannot load (eg API fails)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, onerror

Hi Thank You for the help

I am building an app using react and have used react-google-maps.
In order to pass this course I have to add a warning if the google map API fails to load (eg with an Alert window). I have looked through the documentation and can not see how to add an onerror function or something like that.

my map component is this

```
import React from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, withScriptjs } from 'react-google-maps';
import MapMarkers from './mapmarkers'


const Map = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props)=>{

   return(
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter = { {lat: 53.481385, lng: -2.242011} }
        defaultZoom = { 10 }
      >
        <MapMarkers
        query ={props.query}
        parks={props.parks}
        selectedpark={props.selectedpark}
        resetpark ={props.resetpark.bind(this)}
     />
        </GoogleMap>
   )}

));


export default Map;
```

and in app.js I have this code

```
  <Map
            parks={this.state.parkruns}
            query ={this.state.query}
            selectedpark={this.state.ClickedID}
            resetpark ={this.clearPark.bind(this)}
            googleMapURL='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX'
            loadingElement={<div  style={{ height: `100%` }}tabIndex="-1"/>}
            containerElement={ <div style={{ height: `100vh`, width: '100vw' }}
            role="application"
            tabIndex="-1"
            aria-label="Map showing parkrus in Greater Manchester"
            /> }
            mapElement={ <div style={{ height: `100%` }} tabIndex="-1"/> }
/>
```

as it stands the map works fine and markers load from a different component fine. I just need to add an error alert

once again thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this.
Simply add this line, with your alert

```
window.gm_authFailure = () => {
    }
```

you can find a more information in the Google documentation, right at the bottom.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events